# Python3 read file and place 2D array with int value one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, file-read

I'm interested that this 2 lines can be solved in 1 line:

```
data = [ line.strip().split() for line in f ] # f = file
data = [ [ int(num) for num in nums ] for nums in data ]
```

Example lines of file:

```
9 3 14 3 10 17
9 8 19 12 5 9
```

Example result:

```
[[9, 3, 14, 3, 10, 17], [9, 8, 19, 12, 5, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
data = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in f.readlines()]
print(data)
[[9, 3, 14, 3, 10, 17], [9, 8, 19, 12, 5, 9]]
```

or using numpy can be slightly neater:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("file.txt", dtype=int).tolist()
```